# Is it possible to replace a switch with a receptacle?

Tags: electrical

I moved to this place and I don't know how the wiring works, so I did some tests and couldn't explain the results.

Here's the situation: there's this switch on the wall which only has two wires in it (no ground, no 3rd cable). When I put a test light on it, it lights for one of the wires but not for the other. The switch controls a lamp. I assumed then something like:

`127 V --> switch+ --> lamp+ --> (actual) lamp --> lamp- --> switch- --> neutral`

Where "+" means "the test light is on when I touch it".

Then, I did the following: replaced the switch with an outlet (switch+ became outlet+ and so on), and I expected the following to happen:

- Without anything on the outlet, the circuit would be open and therefore the lamp would not light.
- By inserting some electrical appliance on the outlet, it would close the circuit, allow current to flow, and light both the appliance and the lamp.

What happened instead was that:

- The appliance lit (and it seems to work just fine, with supposedly 127 V), but not the lamp.

How is this possible? Is this a "feature" of some kind of wiring?

Note: this is not in the US, and I know nothing of local regulations about wiring, so I assume it might be non-standard.

Comment: Put it back the way you found it, and walk away slowly.

Comment: Is it dangerous to use it this way? It's a 100W incandescent light bulb and a 5-ish W appliance, so it seems to work as described by DoxyLover: there is not enough current in the lamp to actually light it, but the appliance works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have done is put the two devices in series. Normally, devices are placed in parallel. In series, the voltage is split between the two devices. The actual voltage each device sees depends upon its current rating. A device that draws a higher current (or wattage) will have a lower resistance and lower current a higher resistance. when you connect a high current device in series with a low current device, the low current device will get most of the voltage.

For example, if you connect a 10W radio in series with a 100W light bulb, the radio will get 91% (10/11) of the 127V while the light bulb will only get 9% (1/11) of the 127V. The radio will work pretty normally while the light bulb will barely glow. (Note: this is a bit of a simplification since, for example, the resistance of a light bulb will change as it heats up.)

To further clarify series vs. parallel:

Here's a series circuit:

[image]

(ignore the switch).

Here's a parallel circuit:

[image]

This is the proper way to connect two device to the power.

Comment: Right, I was expecting that there might be some sort of more complicated wiring that would allow this kind of "conversion" to happen, but it's just the simplest and cheapest solution that has been implemented.